# Jquery fadeout not working with Jquery Loaded content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have this problem with Jquery at the moment
The fadeOut function doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
function laadpagina(pagepath, menuid) {
    $('#paginainhoud').fadeOut();
    wait(1000);
    $("#pagecontent").load(pagepath, function(responseText, textStatus, req) {
        if (textStatus == "error") {
            $("#pagecontent").load("/paginas/home.php?404");
        }
    });
    actievemenu.classList.remove("active");
    actievemenu = document.getElementById(menuid);
    actievemenu.classList.add("active");
}
```

It does load the new Path, yet doesn't fade out the other class.
Oh, and yes, i do use `<div id="paginainhoud"></div>` instead of `<div class="paginainhoud"></div>`

The div i try to fade out is loaded using the Jquery Load function, can this be a problem? Oh, And the Inspector Tool doesn't show any type of errors.

Comment: I think you need to switch these 2: `actievemenu.classList.remove("active");
    actievemenu = document.getElementById(menuid);` Your `actievemenu` variable doesnt exists until then, and throws an error. What does your inspector tool say?

Comment: What is this `wait` function?

Answer (score 0):

A problem might be that you're using the slim version of Jquery that does not include the fadeOut() function. [Link to Jquery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) choose the uncompressed / minified version. If you use the links from getbootstrap.com, for example, they use the slim version. You can also check the chrome console (f12) to see if you get an error from the fadeOut() function.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> wait(1000);
> ```

You haven't provided the code for this, but I'm going to assume that it runs a loop of expensive calculations in order to try to fake a sleep function in JavaScript.

Since you have a single event loop to operate on, this keeps the JavaScript engine busy when it would be animating the `fadeOut`.

When the wait loop finishes, the JS checks at what point the animation should be at, discovers that enough time has passed for it to be completely *out* and snaps directly to it because it missed the points where it should have had the partially faded points.

If you want to delay code, put it in a function and pass it to `setTimeout`.

```
$('#paginainhoud').fadeOut();
setTimeout(function () {

    $("#pagecontent").load(pagepath, function(responseText, textStatus, req) {
        if (textStatus == "error") {
            $("#pagecontent").load("/paginas/home.php?404");
        }
    });
    actievemenu.classList.remove("active");
    actievemenu = document.getElementById(menuid);
    actievemenu.classList.add("active");
}, 1000);
```

Better yet, if you just want to wait for the animation to finish, take advantage of the callback feature built into jQuery.

```
$('#paginainhoud').fadeOut({ 
    complete: function () {
        $("#pagecontent").load(pagepath, function(responseText, textStatus, req) {
            if (textStatus == "error") {
                $("#pagecontent").load("/paginas/home.php?404");
            }
        });
        actievemenu.classList.remove("active");
        actievemenu = document.getElementById(menuid);
        actievemenu.classList.add("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed used some calulations to let the code sleep.Thanks for this !